# Unable to upgrade from version 5.10.0 to version 8

Tags: drush, composer

I tried upgrading from Drush 5.10.0 to Drush 8 using `sudo composer global require drush/drush:~8`, but it doesn't update anything.

> Changed current directory to /home/lupiyardo/.composer
>   Running composer as root/super user is highly discouraged as packages, plugins and scripts cannot always be trusted
>   ./composer.json has been updated
>   Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Nothing to install or update
>   Generating autoload files

As confirmation Drush wasn't updated, the output of `drush --version` is *Drush 5.10.0*.

I looked at the composer.json file and it contains `'require': { }`.

How can I upgrade Drush?

Comment: In your return the 2nd line says `Running composer as root/super user is highly discouraged as packages, plugins and scripts cannot always be trusted` are you running this as root? if yes, looks like that may be the problem.

Comment: No Sssweat: He is running this via sudo ,therefore as root. @Sage: Where is your drush script located? Check drush status for that.

Comment: Yea, but i get the same output on terminal without sudo (except for the part about root/super user) and also a permission denied error. That's why I tried it that way.

Comment: _I looked at my composer.json file and it says 'require': { }_ - that's what you'd expect, you asked composer to require the package globally. Your local composer.json shouldn't be affected by that command. And yeah, don't run composer as root, bad things can happen sometimes! Try `composer global remove drush/drush` and re-install with the specific version number you want. And of course make sure `which drush` points to the file under composer's global folder, not anywhere else on your machine (i.e. set you path properly per the composer installation docs)

Comment: you can try this tut http://whaaat.com/installing-drush-8-using-composer. I think you missing step add code
$ export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me in Linux Machine:
    cd /usr/local/bin
    mkdir drush-8
    cd drush-8
    composer require drush/drush:8.x
    ln -s /usr/local/bin/drush-8/vendor/bin/drush /usr/local/bin/drush8

Let me explain a little bit:

- Go to folder `/usr/local/bin`
- Create a new folder `drush-8`  * go
  to the folder above
- Install drush (here more info:
  https://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/ )
- Finally, create a Symbolic Links that point to new `drush` version

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. While it might solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why or how your approach works_ compared to others.

Comment: I hope that helps @ShawnConn